# Spring Security Java Config

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-java-config

So recently I migrated the Spring configuration from XML to Java config.
It's a Spring OAuth 2 Server, and some endpoints are secured with clients authentication, and some endpoints (confirm_access) are secured with user authentication, which is delegated to login application with a redirect made from a filter ("authenticationFilter").
But I'm not able to do the same with Spring Security Java config :

Here my working security XML configuration :

```xml
<sec:http pattern="/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />

<sec:http access-denied-page="/errors/access-denied.html" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/authorize" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="confirm_access" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/device/authorize" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <sec:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" before="ANONYMOUS_FILTER" />
        <sec:anonymous />
    </sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Here is my Java config attempt :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@Order(1)
@Import({WebSecurityConfig.TokenEndpointSecurityConfigurationAdapter.class,
        WebSecurityConfig.ResourceSecurityConfigurationAdapter.class,
        WebSecurityConfig.AnonymousSecurityConfigurationAdapter.class})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsUserService;

    @Bean(name = "clientAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(clientDetailsUserService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)                                                        
    public static class TokenEndpointSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsUserService;

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter;

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .userDetailsService(clientDetailsUserService)
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeUrls()
                .antMatchers("/token")
                .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.stateless)
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAccessDeniedHandler);
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)                                                        
    public static class ResourceSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(4)                                                        
    public static class AnonymousSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

        @Autowired
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeUrls().anyRequest().anonymous()
            .and()
                .authorizeUrls()
                .antMatchers("/authorize","confirm_access","/custom/authorize")
                .hasRole("USER")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errors/access-denied.html");
        }
    }
}
```

With this config Spring Security tries to authenticate user for all endpoints, and displays generate login form, so custom filter is not added.
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: You need two AuthenticationManagers (one for OAuth clients and one for users), but I can see just one in your java-based configuration.

Comment: Hello @Eugen, this is great example, whcih help me. But i have some problem, when i use `addFilterBefore(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)` in HttpSecurity, i get the follwoing compiler error `he method addFilterBefore(Filter, Class<? extends Filter>) from the type HttpSecurity refers to the missing type Filter` how i resolve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your original configuration only contains two `http` elements your new configuration should only contain two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instances. Each `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instance is mapped using the `http.antMatchers`. Currently `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is mapped to every URL.

You can refer to the reference for [an example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) of how to use multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instances (which is the equivalent of )